# Create mp3 previews from wav and aiff files

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, aiff

I would like to create a program that makes mp3s of the first 30 seconds of an aiff or wav file. I would also like to be able to choose location and length, such as the audio between 2:12 and 2:42. Are there any tools that lets me do this?

Shelling out is OK. The application will run on a linux server, so it would have to be a tool that works on linux.

I don't mind doing it in two steps - i.e. a tool that first creates the cutout of the aiff/wav, then pass it to a mp3 encoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to use something as low level as possible, so I ended up using [`RubyAudio`](https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio), a wrapper for [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).

```
require "rubygems"
require "ruby-audio"

EXTRACT_BEGIN = 11.2
EXTRACT_LENGTH = 3.5

RubyAudio::Sound.open("/home/augustl/sandbox/test.aif") do |snd|
  info = snd.info
  ["channels", "format", "frames", "samplerate", "sections", "seekable"].each do |key|
    puts "#{key}: #{info.send(key)}"
  end

  # TODO: should we use a 1000 byte buffer? Does it matter? See RubyAudio::Sound rdocs.
  bytes_to_read = (info.samplerate * EXTRACT_LENGTH).to_i
  buffer = RubyAudio::Buffer.new("float", bytes_to_read, info.channels)

  snd.seek(info.samplerate * EXTRACT_BEGIN)
  snd.read(buffer, bytes_to_read)

  out = RubyAudio::Sound.open("/home/augustl/sandbox/out.aif", "w", info.clone)
  out.write(buffer)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[`SoX`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) with the `trim` predicate can do this. If your sox is not built with MP3 support then you'll have to pipe the output to `lame` after, or find one that is.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LAME](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/lame/lame/USAGE) for the mp3 encoding part. Use [shntplit](http://aidanjm.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/split-lossless-audio-ape-flac-wv-wav-by-cue-file/) to split the file. You will need to put your split points in a cue file, but that is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Run this Bash one-liner in a directory with *.wav files.

```
for wavfile in *.wav; do \
  sox "${wavfile}" "preview-${wavfile}" trim 0 60 fade 3 57 3; \
  lame --preset standard "preview-${wavfile}" \
    "preview-`basename ${wavfile} .wav`".mp3; \
  rm "preview-${wavfile}"; \
done
```

First 60 seconds. 3 seconds fade-in and 3 seconds fade-out. Original wav files stay untouched. Preview files come with a "preview-" prefix. You'll be able to choose location and length by changing "trim 0 60" to fit Your needs.
Requires: sox, lame

If You have a directory with mp3 files and need to create previews, run this:

```
for mp3file in *.mp3; do \
  mpg123 -w "${mp3file}.wav" "${mp3file}"; \
  sox "${mp3file}.wav" "preview-${mp3file}.wav" trim 0 60 fade 3 57 3; \
  rm "${mp3file}.wav"; \
  lame --preset standard "preview-${mp3file}.wav" "preview-${mp3file}"; \
  rm -v "preview-${mp3file}.wav"; \
done
```

Requires: mpg123, sox, lame

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [python library, pydub](http://pydub.com), that makes this trivial, though it uses ffmpeg in to do the conversions in order to support more formats…

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/input/file.aiff", format="aif")

# 2 min and 12 sec, them convert to milliseconds
start = (2*60 + 12) * 1000
end = start +  (30 * 1000)
snip = sound[start:end]

# add 3 second fade in and fade out
snip = snip.fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000)

# save as mp3
snip.export("/output/file.mp3", format="mp3")
```