# Creating preview audio clips from m4a files

Tags: audio, mp3, preview, aac, m4a

Another post here answered the question of creating 30 second preview clips from WAV audio files ([Create mp3 previews from wav and aiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549304/create-mp3-previews-from-wav-and-aiff-files)).  My needs slightly overlap, but differing details are beyond my knowledge.

Requirements/Options: clip length; beginning & ending fade length; input filetypes: m4a/AAC/AIFF; output filetype: mp3; kbps (e.g. 192); original files unaltered; suffix new mp3 names with " (Preview)"

Limitations: no uploading of original files to a server (desktop processing); no compiling (unix/Terminal/Bash script only); recursive processing of files in sub-directories

Any/All assistance and advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely get the best results with a DAW (digital audio workstation) and an audio file converter.

For a DAW, Reaper comes with a 60 day trial, and it has everything you need to cut the songs where you need and to do fade ins/fade outs, and other effects if you'd like.

www.reaper.fm

Simply use a converter to convert the m4a file to .wav, .mp3 or whatever you prefer, and then if you need it back in m4a, convert it back. I say this because some DAWs can't work with m4a files, but if which ever one you choose to work with can then no conversion is necessary,

There are many options for what DAW and what converter you use, I recommend Reaper for a DAW, and most converters essentially do the same thing, so it doesn't make much of a difference which one you choose.

Hope this helps!